# simple spell checking tool in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, intellisense, generator

What i'm tying to achieve is a input field where you can put in how you think you spell the word then it will search my text file named words.txt and will find words that are of similar spelling then it will put the results into a new window.

thanks in advance

Comment: I think what your looking for sounds a lot like [Intellisense](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5839/DIY-Intellisense)?

Comment: Hi Kysumi, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Are you doing this in Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Hi im trying to do this in Microsoft visual C# im a beginner and im hoping someone would be able to provide a example of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I have used and it sounded exactly what you wanted:

[Make similar suggestions for input text by remembering old inputs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11007/Make-similar-suggestions-for-input-text-by-remembe)

You can see it in action [in the screen capture video here](http://eventanalyser.appointmentsbook.com)

ps I pre-populated a dictionary.dic file to suit in one instance and in the above example I did some other rules around LogParsers `SQL-Like` syntax to provide intellisense. HTH